# Redux - 'map function' is not rendered after props changed but 'input value' is rendered

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

For example, the below one is rendered without any issues in redux.

```
<Input type="textarea"  value={this.props.description}
                                       onChange={this.descriptionChange}/>
```

But, this one is never rendered after 'props.permissions' is changed. Definitely the redux util in Chrome indicates 'props.permissions' is already changed.

```
                           </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody> {
                                    this.props.permissions.map((permission, i) => (
                                        <tr className={'text-center'} key={i}>
                                            <td>
                                                <Input type={"checkbox"}/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div> {permission.id}</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div>{permission.module_value}</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div>{permission.name}</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div>{permission.uri}</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div>{permission.description}</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))

                                }
```

I am aware that if I use 'setState' instead of 'redux', the map function re-renders the screen.

Also here comes the full code.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    Table,
    Pagination,
    PaginationItem,
    PaginationLink,
    Row,
    Col,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Collapse,
    Card,
    CardHeader,
    CardBody,
    TabContent,
    TabPane,
    DropdownToggle,
    DropdownMenu,
    DropdownItem,
    Button,
    Input,
    InputGroup,
    InputGroupAddon,
    InputGroupText,
    InputGroupButtonDropdown
} from 'reactstrap';


import Axios from 'axios';



import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FIELD_GROUP_PERMISSION, FIELD_PERMISSION_LISTS} from '../../../../../actions/permission';


class Register extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pSelected: [],

            splitButtonOpen: false,
            isOpen: false,
            collapse: true,
            listDate: [
                {listName: "abc"},
                {listName: "qed"}
            ],
            listModule: [
                {item: "default1"},
                {item: "default2"},
                {item: "default3"},
            ],
            listCounter: [
                {counter: 100},
                {counter: 500},
                {counter: 1000},
            ]
            ,
            permissions: [


            ],

            moduleList: [
                {
                    name: "모두",
                    value: 'all',
                },
                {
                    name: "웹",
                    value: 'web',
                },
                {
                    name: "네이티브",
                    value: 'native'
                }
            ]
        }


        this.moduleChange = ev => this.props.moduleChange(ev.target.value);


        this.nameChange = ev => this.props.nameChange(ev.target.value);
        this.descriptionChange = ev => this.props.descriptionChange(ev.target.value);


        this.doRegister = this.doRegister.bind(this);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'bg-light'}>
                <Card>

                    <CardHeader className={'font-weight-bold'}>그룹 권한 등록</CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Form>
                            <FormGroup row>
                                <Label for={"selectModule"} sm={2}>Module Select</Label>
                                <Col sm={10}>
                                    <select onChange={this.moduleChange} value={this.props.module}
                                            id="pageCounter">
                                        {this.state.moduleList.map((module, i) => (
                                            <option key={i}
                                                    value={module.value}
                                            >{module.name}</option>
                                        ))}
                                    </select>
                                </Col>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for={"gName"}>Group Name</Label>
                                <Input type={"text"} name={"gName"} id={"gName"}
                                       placeholder={"Input Group Name...."} value={this.props.name}
                                       onChange={this.nameChange}/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for={"gDesc"}>Group Desc</Label>
                                <Input type={"textarea"} name={"gDesc"} id={"gDesc"} value={this.props.description}
                                       onChange={this.descriptionChange}/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <div>
                                    <Table hover responsive
                                           className="table-outline mb-0 d-none d-sm-table">
                                        <thead className="thead-light">
                                        <tr className={'text-center'}>
                                            <th>
                                                <InputGroup>
                                                    <InputGroupAddon addonType={"prepend"}>
                                                        <InputGroupText>
                                                            <Input addon type={"checkbox"}
                                                                   className={"bg-light"}/>
                                                        </InputGroupText>
                                                    </InputGroupAddon>
                                                    <span>Select</span>
                                                </InputGroup>
                                            </th>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Module</th>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Uri</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>

                                        {
                                            this.props.permissions.map((permission, i) => (
                                                <tr className={'text-center'} key={i}>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <Input type={"checkbox"}/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div> {permission.id}</div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div>{permission.module_value}</div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div>{permission.name}</div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div>{permission.uri}</div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div>{permission.description}</div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            ))

                                        }


                                        </tbody>
                                    </Table>

                                    <nav className={"mt-3 w-100"}>
                                        <Pagination className={"justify-content-end"}>
                                            <PaginationItem disabled>
                                                <PaginationLink previous href="#"/>
                                            </PaginationItem>
                                            <PaginationItem active>
                                                <PaginationLink href="#">
                                                    1
                                                </PaginationLink>
                                            </PaginationItem>
                                            <PaginationItem>
                                                <PaginationLink href="#">
                                                    2
                                                </PaginationLink>
                                            </PaginationItem>
                                            <PaginationItem>
                                                <PaginationLink href="#">
                                                    3
                                                </PaginationLink>
                                            </PaginationItem>
                                            <PaginationItem>
                                                <PaginationLink href="#">
                                                    4
                                                </PaginationLink>
                                            </PaginationItem>
                                            <PaginationItem>
                                                <PaginationLink href="#">
                                                    5
                                                </PaginationLink>
                                            </PaginationItem>
                                            <PaginationItem>
                                                <PaginationLink next href="#"/>
                                            </PaginationItem>
                                        </Pagination>
                                    </nav>
                                </div>

                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup className={'float-right'}>
                                <Button color={'danger'} className={'float-right'} onClick={this.doRegister}>등록</Button>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </CardBody>

                </Card>

            </div>
        );
    }

    componentWillMount() {

        Axios.get('/api/indexPermissions?module=' + this.state.moduleList[0].value).then(response => {

            if (response.data.success === 1) {
                this.props.permissionsChange(response.data.permissions);
                this.forceUpdate();
            }

        }).catch(error => {

            console.log(error);
            alert(error);

        });

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
/*        if (nextProps['permissions'] !== this.props.permissions) {
            this.props.permissionsChange(response.data.permissions);
        }*/
/*
        console.log(nextProps);
        if (this.props.permissions) {

            console.log(nextProps);

            if (nextProps.permissions !== this.permissions) {

                alert('aaa');
            }
        }
*/

    }

    doRegister() {

        console.log(this.props);

    }

}

Register.defaultProps = {
    permissions: []
};
/* reducer, redux */
let mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        ...state
    };
}

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        moduleChange: (module) => {
            dispatch({type: FIELD_GROUP_PERMISSION, key: 'module', value: module})
        },
        nameChange: (name) => {
            dispatch({type: FIELD_GROUP_PERMISSION, key: 'name', value: name})
        },
        descriptionChange: (description) => {
            dispatch({type: FIELD_GROUP_PERMISSION, key: 'description', value: description})
        },

        permissionsChange: (permissions) => {
            dispatch({type: FIELD_PERMISSION_LISTS, key: 'permissions', value: permissions})
        }
    }
}
Register = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);


export default Register;
```

The following is the Redux code.

```
    import { FIELD_GROUP_PERMISSION, FIELD_PERMISSION_LISTS } from '../../actions/permission';

export default (state = {}, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

        case FIELD_GROUP_PERMISSION:
            return { ...state, [action.key]: action.value };

        case FIELD_PERMISSION_LISTS:

            return { ...state, [action.key]: action.value };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your Redux code? I think you don't update your array correctly. Are you using the Concat() function to create a new copy of the array in your reducer?

Comment: Thanks. I just uploaded it.

Comment: Did you check what the return value of the `FIELD_PERMISSION_LISTS` case is? If the value of `action.value` is an array you can't set your state like this. Can you try the following approach?
`case FIELD_PERMISSION_LISTS:
            return { ...state, [action.key]: action.value.concat() };`

Comment: Are you sure the axios call is returning a case with response.data.success === 1 ??

Comment: I just found that input type also does not render the view...

Comment: let mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        name :  state.permission.name,
        description : state.permission.description,
        permissions: state.permission.permissions,
    };
}               <-- finally this has solved the issue.